# Adobe Acrobat Pro Javascript, Extract PDF Files

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to extract a set of PDF Files in my folder in Adobe Pro, I got them to extract PDF files larger than 2 pages and saves those extracts as new documents to my new folder.

My problem is if I try to extract a PDF file only 2 pages nothing happens I still want to move the file to the folder even if it's not larger than 2 pages.

```
 var re = /\.pdf$/i;

var filename = this.documentFileName.replace(re, "");
try {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.numPages; i = i + 2) {
        var j = i + 1;
        if (j >= this.numPages)
            j = i;
        this.extractPages({
            nStart: i,
            nEnd: j,
            cPath: "/C/PDF/NewFiles/" + filename + "_" + (i+1) + ".pdf"
        });
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.println("Aborted: " + e)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var re = /\.pdf$/i;
var filename = this.documentFileName.replace(re,"");
var n = 1;
var nParts = Math.ceil(this.numPages/998); 
var nleft = Math.ceil(this.numPages/nParts); 
var remainder = Math.floor(nleft)-1
    try {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.numPages; i+= nleft)
        {    
            var oNewDoc = this.extractPages({nStart: i,nEnd: (((i+remainder)>=this.numPages) ? this.numPages-1 : (i+remainder))});
            oNewDoc.newPage({nPage: 0});
            oNewDoc.addWatermarkFromText({cText: filename,nStart: 0,nFontSize:14, nTextAlign: app.constants.align.center});
            oNewDoc.addWatermarkFromText({cText: " \n\n\n\nPart "+n + " of " + nParts,nStart: 0,nFontSize:18, nTextAlign: app.constants.align.center});
            //oNewDoc.addWatermarkFromText({cText: remainder,nStart: 0,nFontSize:18, nTextAlign: app.constants.align.center});
            oNewDoc.saveAs({cPath: "/K/Penta/Split/"+filename+"_" +"Part_" + ("0000" + n).slice(-4)  +".pdf"});
            n++;
            oNewDoc.closeDoc(true);
        }
   } catch (e) { console.println("Aborted: " + e) }
```